# REST Calls from a Liferay Portlet

Tags: spring, rest, liferay

I'm trying to setup a simple Liferay + Maven portlet that can utilize REST services to fetch data from an external database. I believe I'm most of the way there but I'm stuck on the `@RequestMapping` within a Liferay portlet. I have a `@Controller` setup that runs fine on the View phase of the portlet

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping(value = "VIEW")
public class RiskController {

     @ActionMapping
        public void handleActionRequest(ActionRequest request, ActionResponse response)throws Exception {
            return;
        }

        @RenderMapping
        public ModelAndView handleRenderRequest(RenderRequest request, RenderResponse response, ModelMap model) {
          model.addAttribute("helloWord", "123");
          return new ModelAndView("index", model);

        }
    }
```

Now I'd like to write some service classes and fetch my data, but I'm not sure how to set this up as far as the Paths/URLs are concerned from a Liferay perspective (i.e., `localhost:8080/myPortlet/myAjaxCall`). I want to do something basic like return an Object via JSON like so

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/getMyData/123", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public @ResponseBody Data getData(@RequestParam long gcfId) {
    Data data = dataRepo.getMyData(123);
    return data;
}
```

Can anyone help get me in the right direction? Can provide more code if needed

Comment: Rather than getting external data via web-services on server side, you can handle it on client side via AJAX calls, when page first loads.

Comment: Your `@Controller`'s `@ResourceMapping` is responsible for entertaining AJAX calls to your portlet from screens.

Comment: I think, you are confusing yourself. You can load data from remote database in `@RenderMapping` via `Client`of 3rd party on server-side as well.

Comment: @ParkashKumar thanks Prakash, but how to make an AJAX call on an event? Do I need to use <portlet:resourceURL> and then the path of my RequestMapping as the Ajax URL?

Comment: You can use `jQuery.ajax` on your view, if you directly want data to appear on page load. Same can be achieved from `@RenderMapping`: get data from remote server, and set it to UI.